# Cloning commercial beer

Tags: clone-recipe, techniques, recipe

Where do you turn for good sources of info when researching a commercial beer you want to brew yourself?
Magazines, web or the brewers themselves.

Comment: I'm going to answer with community wikis and whatnot cuz it's subjective and there might be more than one right answer.

Comment: Why can't someone post one comprehensive answer and get credit for it?

Comment: That works too. If someone does that, sweet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Web

Some websites are better than others for this, but there are some great resources out there for clone recipes. There are the "industry" sites, like [BYO](http://byo.com), that list recipes. There are forums, like [Homebrew Talk](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/), that have great discussions about various clones. And there are recipe sharing sites, like [BeerTools.com](http://www.beertools.com/html/recipes.php) and [Beer Calculus](http://beercalculus.hopville.com/), that have some great variations and consistent details.

Comment: Yeah.  Google first for me, which usually turns up threads at HomebrewTalk.

Comment: Sharing sites really bother me because I think many guys just throw up some random pale ale recipe that they have never brewed.

Answer (score 1):

### Magazines

Some magazines, like Brew Your Own and Zymurgy, provide clone recipes, as well as other recipes for the readers to try. This is a great resource, as they usually delve deeper than just the ingredients. They tend to explain the why of each choice, process, etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Trial and Error

Understanding what goes into beer at a detailed level allows a brewer to taste a beer, look at the color, etc., and make educated guesses on how to mimic it. This is definitely advanced, but with practice, this is a great way to clone a beer.

Answer (score 1):

### Books

There are several books available full of clone recipes, such as [Clone Brews](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/160342539X) or [Beer Captured](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0970344252).

Answer (score 0):

### Podcasts

Podcasts like those put on by [The Brewing Network](http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/), and in particular [The Jamil Show](http://thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/The-Jamil-Show) are a good resource for clone recipes.  The show's format changed a couple years back to what is now called "Can You Brew It," in which a listener will request the hosts clone a commercial brew.  They'll speak with the commercial brewer, get tips and often the actual recipe, then they'll try their best to clone it.  It is very informative and entertaining.